# Launch new activity (within same app) after login successful

Tags: android, android-webview

Following is my code for URL overriding. After users logs in successfully, my main activity loads next webpage. But I want to redirect to new activity(within my app only) so that user experience is made better. How do I do this? Following code isn't working. I tracked successful login event using Debugger in Firefox and used that particular part of URL "app?service".

Note: This code works only after any click event happens in newly loaded webpage. I want this to happen automatically after successful login.

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains("app?service")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Status.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", url);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //my code
        }
    });
```

Can you please help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move your code in `onPageFinished()` method

```
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.contains("app?service")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Status.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", url);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried, but this doesn't work. In onPageFinished method, I've written code to process my login page.

Comment: I tried this with different URL and and new Android WebView app. **This works! Simple and fast!** _Needn't even do_ 
   `Intent.puExtra("url", url);`
as WebView loads with new URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, this method will call automatically.

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.contains("app?service")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Status.class);
                        intent.putExtra("url", url);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        //return true;
                    }
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. I tried this with WebChromeClient and WebViewClient, but nothing happens, actually it gives error for super method, so replacing super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url) with null, removed errors.

Comment: can you please explain why to use `public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url){}` ? What advantage it offers over `public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {}` ? Thanks.